# How set a textTabs into a embedded signer and then remove the signer

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to set "effective date" without Routing Order. So I have 3 signers one of them is an embedded signer. So the idea (thanks Larry K) is after the regular signers completed their signs, I will set a textTabs with the current date and then remove the embedder signer so the envelope change their status to completed.

So I am doing this.

POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

recipientId = is the id of the embedded signer

```
{
"textTabs": [
    {
        "tabId": "effectiveDate",
        "value": "31 August 2020",
        "locked": "true",
        "font": "Calibri",
        "fontSize": "Size9",
        "bold": "true",
        "anchorString": "**sd**",
        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
        "anchorYOffset": "-2", 
        "anchorXOffset": "-5"
    }
]
}
```

After that I delete the embedded signer and the envelope is completed, but the value of the textTabs is not showing in any document.
This is part of the response of the POST after created the textTabs in the embedded signer.

```
{
"textTabs": [
    {
        "isPaymentAmount": "false",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "requireAll": "false",
        "value": "31 August 2020",
        "required": "true",
        "locked": "true",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "maxLength": "0",
        "font": "calibri",
        "bold": "true",
        "italic": "false",
        "underline": "false",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "localePolicy": {},
        "documentId": "3",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "130",
        "yPosition": "74",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "anchorString": "**sd**",
        "anchorXOffset": "-5",
        "anchorYOffset": "-2",
        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
        "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
        "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
        "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
        "tabId": "3cf87755-ee56-4bb2-94bb-25fc5309c66c",
        "tabType": "text"
    }...
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are associated with signers, if you remove the signer - the tabs for it will be removed.
So, not sure what you were trying to do here, but if you remove a recipient in DocuSign, it will remove any tabs (text tabs, sign her tabs, date tabs) that were tied to this recipient.

Comment: Is there any way to set a text into a document that is not tied to a recipient?

Comment: Just add the text tab to a signer that you're not deleting...

Comment: Mariano, if you need text that is not tied to a recipient, why not use a tool to create your document? DocuSign also has CLM capabilities but that may be an overkill. I would just dynamically generate your document on the fly and add it to the envelope with the information you need.

Comment: The issue for me is that I need to set the date of the last signer, but I don't want to use routing order. I'm already using docxtemplater to generate documents with a lot of dynamical information, but the signed date it must be setting by docusing when the last signer complete the process (sign) I know that if I use routing order I can do it, but now we have another process to sign agreements and we don't want to follow an order, we want that any signer could sign at any moment and not to wait to another signer. I don't know why is so hard to do that.

Comment: So, you want to have multiple signers (3?) and have them sign whenever they want (no routing order) and then have a tab that says "last signer signed on _____" with the date and time of the last signer? That's an interesting one....

Comment: adding another answer, it's for your other question that was answered by Larry with a modified solution that would actually work (but it's complicated).

Comment: Inbar, exactly what you say is what I want, sadly I don’t understand why is so hard to do it. :(

Comment: the reason it's hard is that a "Signed Date" field (or any field) is legally associated with a person. You cannot have a field that is not associated with someone because of legal reasons.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but DS finally knows who is the last signer without using routing order, they must offer a "dateSignedTabs" conditional that only apply when the real last signer finish the sign process, so simply as that.

Comment: I can ask for a new feature, but typically the date is associated with a specific individual, that is what most customers ask for.

Comment: This new feature could be also be associated to a recipient/signer, today DS offer some conditional custom tabs I believe, this new feature could be something like this but print or execute this new tab if the condition of last signer is true, and you can use this new signedDateTabs without knowing or follow the routing order.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are complicated, here is a modified solution to your original question that was answered by Larry that should work if you follow this:

Add a new integration user as a Certified Delivery recipient at the end of the envelope
once everyone signs, webhook pings the app
app checks the Date Signed values for each recipient
app creates a text field for the CD recipient and populates it with the last value (test in demo, this used to be possible and likely still is but isn't actually supported)
app changes CD recipient to CC (also test to make sure the role change doesn't wipe the field. Again, used to work, likely still does)
envelope completes with text field populated

Comment: Well finally I give up, I try your idea Inbar, but also y no working. If you have some REST Api code that work for your, please shared. Any way, thanks a lot for your time guys!!!

Comment: I'm sorry Mariano, this one is difficult, but I understand your frustration.